# Summing java.sql.Time objects

Tags: java, datetime, time

I have a list of time objects (representing the length of a song) that I would like to add together to get the total time.

Looking at the documentation for `java.sql.Time` objects it seems that the date part should be untouched and the number of milliseconds will represent the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970, with a negative value meaning before 1970.

I have a Time object (lets call it `time`) in the format `00:06:25` i.e 6 mins 25 secs.
If I call `new Date(time.getTime())` I get Thu Jan 01 00:06:25, which is sensible.
However, when I simply print the value of `getTime()` I get a value of -3215000, which makes absolutely no sense, this value would indicate that the time was before 1 Jan 1970...which it isn't.

Therefore when I try to add multiple calls of `getTime()` together (like 00:03:35/-3385000) I get a more and more negative number (-6600000).

So when I then try and create a new `Time` object with that value I get 23:10:00 rather than 00:09:00.

Comment: `java.sql.Time` isn't really appropriate for this. That's a time of day. I would store an integer value in the database - a number of milliseconds, for example.

Comment: It sounds like this is the wrong abstraction for you, if `Time` objects represent a time in the universe rather than an amount of time that supports addition.  What should April 3 2015 plus September 7 1991 be?

Comment: I completely agree, but it forms a tiny part of a practice exercise where it was already chosen to use `java.sql.Time` and it's just bugging me

Answer (score 0):

I created a test job that displayed the following output:

```
1 Jan 1970 00:06:25 GMT
1 Jan 1970 00:03:35 GMT
1 Jan 1970 00:03:18 GMT
1 Jan 1970 00:04:22 GMT
1 Jan 1970 00:03:47 GMT
1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

1 Jan 1970 00:21:27 GMT
```

The last Time is the sum of the preceding 6 times

The trick is to use the toGMTString() (depreciated) method of Time to generate the output string.

Here's the code I used:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.sql.Time;

public class AddDates implements Runnable {

    private Time[] songLength;

    public AddDates() {
        this.songLength = new Time[6];
        long time = (6L * 60 + 25) * 1000;
        songLength[0] = new Time(time);
        time = (3L * 60 + 35) * 1000;
        songLength[1] = new Time(time);
        time = (3L * 60 + 18) * 1000;
        songLength[2] = new Time(time);
        time = (4L * 60 + 22) * 1000;
        songLength[3] = new Time(time);
        time = (3L * 60 + 47) * 1000;
        songLength[4] = new Time(time);
        time = 0L;
        songLength[5] = new Time(time);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long sum = 0L;
        for (int i = 0; i < songLength.length; i++) {
            sum += songLength[i].getTime();
            System.out.println(songLength[i].toGMTString());
        }

        Time totalTime = new Time(sum);
        System.out.println(totalTime.toGMTString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AddDates().run();
    }

}
```